# Maven Fatal error compiling: directory not found: maven-compiler-plugin

Tags: class, maven, directory, glassfish, target

I am trying to run the official Java EE 7 Tutorial code examples and get the error. I have read about it here and most of the results say that you have to check that your Maven plugin target is the same than your system JDK environment variable. My JDK_HOME is:

[image: jdk home image]

Here is my parent POM.XML:

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.javaeetutorial</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaeetutorial</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.5</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>javaeetutorial</name>
    
    <scm>
        <connection>scm:svn:https://svn.java.net/svn/javaeetutorial~svn/tags/javaeetutorial-7.0.0</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://svn.java.net/svn/javaeetutorial~svn/tags/javaeetutorial-7.0.0</developerConnection>
    </scm>
    <issueManagement>
        <system>IssueTracker</system>
        <url>http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVAEETUTORIAL</url>
    </issueManagement>
  
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <javaee.api.version>7.0</javaee.api.version>
        <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.2</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
        <maven.source.plugin.version>2.2.1</maven.source.plugin.version>
        <maven.clean.plugin.version>2.5</maven.clean.plugin.version>
        <maven.war.plugin.version>2.3</maven.war.plugin.version>
        <maven.acr.plugin.version>1.0</maven.acr.plugin.version>
        <maven.ear.plugin.version>2.8</maven.ear.plugin.version>
        <maven.ejb.plugin.version>2.3</maven.ejb.plugin.version>
        <maven.jar.plugin.version>2.4</maven.jar.plugin.version>
        <maven.rar.plugin.version>2.3</maven.rar.plugin.version>
        <maven.license.plugin.version>1.10.b1</maven.license.plugin.version>
        <maven.release.plugin.version>2.4.1</maven.release.plugin.version>
        <maven.exec.plugin.version>1.2.1</maven.exec.plugin.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <eclipselink.version>2.5.0</eclipselink.version>
        <glassfish.embedded.version>4.0</glassfish.embedded.version>
        <cargo.plugin.version>1.4.4</cargo.plugin.version>
        <glassfish.domain.name>domain1</glassfish.domain.name>
        <glassfish.home>${glassfish.home.prefix}/glassfish4</glassfish.home>
        <integration.container.id>glassfish4x</integration.container.id>
    </properties>
    
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>windows</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>windows</family>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <glassfish.home.prefix>c:/</glassfish.home.prefix>
                <glassfish.executables.suffix>.bat</glassfish.executables.suffix>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>unix</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>unix</family>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <glassfish.home.prefix>${user.home}</glassfish.home.prefix>
                <glassfish.executables.suffix />
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>sdk</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <glassfish.home>${basedir}/../../../</glassfish.home>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>development</id>
            <activation>
                <file>
                    <exists>${basedir}/../bundle</exists>
                </file>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <glassfish.home>${glassfish.home.prefix}/glassfish4</glassfish.home>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>standalone</id>
            <properties>
                <glassfish.home>${basedir}/target/cargo/installs/glassfish</glassfish.home>
                <cargo.maven.containerUrl>http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/4.0/promoted/latest-glassfish.zip</cargo.maven.containerUrl>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    
    <modules>
        <module>archetypes</module>
        <module>batch</module>
        <module>case-studies</module>
        <module>cdi</module>
        <module>concurrency</module>
        <module>connectors</module>
        <module>ejb</module>
        <module>jaxrs</module>
        <module>jaxws</module>
        <module>jms</module>
        <module>persistence</module>
        <module>security</module>
        <module>web</module>
    </modules>
    
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>snapshot-repository.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Snapshot Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/staging/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>releases-repository.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net releases Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven.source.plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven.clean.plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven.war.plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${cargo.plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>deploy</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>redeploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <container>
                        <containerId>${integration.container.id}</containerId>
                        <type>installed</type>
                        <home>${glassfish.home}</home>
                    </container>
                    <configuration>
                        <type>existing</type>
                        <home>${glassfish.home}/glassfish/domains</home>
                        <properties>
                            <cargo.glassfish.domain.name>${glassfish.domain.name}</cargo.glassfish.domain.name>
                            <!--cargo.remote.username></cargo.remote.username-->
                            <cargo.remote.password />
                        </properties>
                    </configuration>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mycila.maven-license-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-license-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.license.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <header>common/license.txt</header>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>common/**</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/META-INF/**</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/WEB-INF/**</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/nbactions.xml</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/nb-configuration.xml</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/glassfish-resources.xml</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/simple-flow-flow.xml</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.release.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!--
                     During release:perform, enable the "sdk" profile
                    -->
                    <releaseProfiles>sdk</releaseProfiles>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javaee.api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

My child POM.XML

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>servlet</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.javaeetutorial</groupId>
        <version>7.0.5</version>
    </parent>
    
    <groupId>org.glassfish.javaeetutorial</groupId>
    <artifactId>hello2</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.5</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>hello2</name>   
</project>
```

after I run MVN install I get the error:

[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are compiling a project inside your Program Files. 
Those folders are often write protected.

Re-install Glassfish into a Document folder where read/write is not an issue.

Maven does not tend to have the world's most helpful error messages - here the issue is not that directory cannot be found, it seems more like a directory could not be created!